# SQLCMD vs SSMS performance

Tags: ssms, sqlcmd

I wrote a script, that takes long enough to run.
It looks like this:

```
        set nocount on
        select 1
        GO
        select 2
        GO
        select 1
        GO
        select 2
        GO
```

and this repeats for long. In SSMS it takes more than 1 minute to complete, while in SQLCMD it takes no longer than one second. **Is sqlcmd always that much faster than SSMS?**

This is the command that is passed to sqlcmd:

```
       -i filepath\test.sql -v FilePath = "filepath\test2.sql" -r -S servername -d dbname -U username -P password
```

where test.sql contains:

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    :r $(FilePath)
    GO
```

because it doesn't seem to be a problem to set nocount on two times, and this program is running hundreds of scripts, where many of them doesn't have nocount on.

sqlcmd version: 2005.90.5000

SSMS version: 2011.110.3000

Comment: Sorry, could not get a real question? What would you like to archive: have a script and have it executed on demand(on schedule) or you just want to have you things done 1 time but fast?

Comment: I'm just curious. It doesn't really matter why I need this application. I can't figure out why can SQLCMD execute the same script a hundred times faster than SSMS. And it is sure it executes it, because I have an output file, and it contains all the output of the select statements I wrote.